# Select from pandas dataframe and ignore columns with zero values

Tags: pandas, boolean, slice

I am selecting rows from a dataframe with datetimeindex. When selecting, I would like to automatically exclude those columns that have only zero values.

I came up with a list comprehension that does the test.

```
test = [data[i].isin([1]).any(0) for i in data.columns]
```

How can I now apply this test on a slice of the dataframe?

```
data[test]
```

gives me a ValueError: Item wrong length.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The quickest method IMO is to just filter the whole df and then drop the resulting `NaN` values (using [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html#pandas.DataFrame.dropna)setting a threshold on the column axis of at least 1 non-`NaN` value:

```
In [29]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':0, 'c':[0,0,1]})
df
Out[29]:
   a  b  c
0  1  0  0
1  2  0  0
2  3  0  1
In [37]:

df[df!=0].dropna(axis=1, thresh=1)
Out[37]:
   a   c
0  1 NaN
1  2 NaN
2  3   1
```

You can then use the result of the filtered df however you wish without worrying about invalid column values

Comment: Hi @EdChum! Thanks for your help. I upvoted your answer because it was helping me getting the job done. Thanks a lot for it! I am not sure whether it is really the answer to my question, though (How to apply the test to the dataframe). Perhaps someone else can answer that question?

Comment: The boolean test `df!=0` specifically masks the entire df so will produce a True/False mask when used to mask the df this will put `NaN` values where the mask is `False` we can then drop these values column-wise (using `axis=1` but we only drop these if all values in the column are `NaN` as your desired